# Is it possible to remove the QGIS icon from dialogs windows using pyqt?

Tags: qgis-plugins, pyqt

I am developing a QGIS plugin using PyQt 4.x and the QGIS API. The plugin uses several dialog windows (QDialog Class). Some of them (I don't know why some do and others don't) show the Qgis icon on the top left part of the frame. I am trying to remove all icons from all dialogs using Qt.WindowFlags.

In most of them the following works:

```
dialog_window.setWindowFlags(Qt.CustomizeWindowHint | Qt.WindowTitleHint)
```

result:

[image]

when I want to keep the closewindowHintButton:

```
dialog_window.setWindowFlags(Qt.CustomizeWindowHint | Qt.WindowTitleHint | Qt.WindowCloseButtonHint)
```

the logo does not go away and I end up with this:

[image]
I also tried to set up the `setWindowIcon()` method to an empty `QIcon()` instance, still the logo does not want to disappear.

Has anyone ever found a solution to this?